# Move File Field storage from public:// to another stream wrapper (like s3://)

Tags: files, stream-wrappers

I've been looking around for this a bit, and it seems like it would be relatively easy in Drupal 7, since D7 supports stream wrappers, and Fields are part of core... but I can't find any documentation.

I have a file field with a few thousand files attached to nodes, and it's using public:// right now.

I also have the [AmazonS3](http://drupal.org/project/amazons3) module installed, and some other file fields are already set to use the s3:// stream wrapper.

I now want to migrate the file field using `public://` to `s3://`, and I want all the files already uploaded to the site's files folder to switch to s3. I can manually copy over the files to a bucket on S3, but what exactly would I need to do in Drupal/the database to get the files to be loaded over s3 instead of public?

I thought about just writing a custom query to update all rows in the `file_managed` table with `public://custom/path` to change to `s3://custom/path`, but (a) there are some older files that were migrated with different paths than `custom/path`, and (b) I'm not sure if this is the right way to get Drupal to use S3.

[**Edit**: Just noticed the file_move() function in the API—would I be able to move files using this (after switching the field storage in the Field UI) instead of having to manually copy files and update the database?].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the paths that match across the two servers you can just change the paths in `file_managed` to start with `s3://`, clear the caches, and the S3 module will handle the rest.

[This module](http://drupal.org/node/1450816#comment-6300902) should be really helpful, I've just written a module for someone which is pretty similar to what you're trying to do (except the files are pruned from the local file system to S3 on a cron) and the module in that link was a great starting point.

Since the S3 module implements a fully functional stream wrapper you can use all of the usual file functions (`file_copy`, `file_move`, `file_delete`, etc) as normal, without having to worry about where the files are.